# How to customize FaExclamationTriangle?

Tags: css, react-icons

I am using FaExclamationTriangle in my react component I want to customize it so that can look like :
[image: ![enter image description here]

When I am applying yellow color css to icon it showing yellow triangle with white exclamation.

[image]